# Extracting YYYY-MM from datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I've a dataframe of this format -

```
var1  date
A     2017/01/01
A     2017/01/02
...
```

I want the date to be converted into `YYYY-MM` format but the `df['date'].dtype` is `object`.
How can I remove the day part from date while keeping the data type as datetime?

Expected Output -

```
A - 2017/01
```

Thanks

Comment: you need to parse the current dates first - there's a parse_dates argument when you read a csv files. Then you can convert to whichever output you want. Alternatively just use a lambda function df.date.apply(lambda x: x[0:4] + "/" + x[4:5])

Comment: `How can I remove the day part from date while keeping the data type as datetime?`. This is not possible. As in real life, each date has a day. Choose what you want: a string (with whatever components you like) or datetime (with all components, even if they aren't all *displayed*).

Comment: @jpp, we can use a `period` dtype as a compromise between `datetime` and `object` dtypes...

Comment: @MaxU, Fair point. Thanks for reopening with a valid compromise :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't have custom representation for the `datetime` dtype. But you have the following options:

1. use strings - you might have any representation (as you wish), but all datetime methods and attributes get lost
2. use `datetime`, but set the `day` part to `1` (as @Kopytok) has already shown.
3. use [`period` dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/timeseries.html#period), which still allows you to use some date arithmetic

---

Demo:

```
In [207]: df
Out[207]:
  var1       date
0    A 2018-12-31
1    A 2017-09-07
2    B 2016-02-29

In [208]: df['new'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('M')

In [209]: df
Out[209]:
  var1       date     new
0    A 2018-12-31 2018-12
1    A 2017-09-07 2017-09
2    B 2016-02-29 2016-02

In [210]: df.dtypes
Out[210]:
var1            object
date    datetime64[ns]
new             object
dtype: object

In [211]: df['new'] + 8
Out[211]:
0   2019-08
1   2018-05
2   2016-10
Name: new, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible replace every date with the first day of month:

```
pd.to_datetime(d["date"], format="%Y/%m/%d").apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1))
```

**Result**:

```
0 2017-01-01
1 2017-01-01
```

Comment: dtype is object. i need it as datetime

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question, which *requires* a compromise. A `datetime` object can't have day "removed".